# How to find reduce similar words from column of list in python using nltk?

Tags: python, pandas, nltk, wordnet, lsa

I have a column in pandas as below

```
0    ['business', 'ceremony', 'festival', 'group']

1    ['mountain', 'outdoors', 'travel', 'tree', 'forest']

2    ['people', 'city', 'politics', 'architecture']

3    ['people', 'politics', 'protest', 'travel']

4    ['automobile', 'business', 'police', 'transporation']
```

I want to find the similar words and reduce to few words to represent the column 
i.e reduce the similar words and use the most common one.

Input:

```
[automobile, business, police, transportation, vehicle]
```

Output:

```
[Vehicle, business, police]
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: This question requires an involved answer. Show your efforts first.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. I'm afraid this kind of question is not a good fit for this site. Ask again when you've made more progress and you have a specific question. See the help section for more...